# Communicating details of method result?

Tags: c++, exceptions, logging

I have code like this (pseudocode)

```
foreach(Box box in boxes)
{
    if(boxFilter.PassesFilter(box))
    {
      // do something useful
    }
    else
    {
      Log.Log(format("Box %s was rejected", box.BoxId))
    }
}
```

But now I'm thinking I'd like the log message to have more information such as "Box 1 rejected because too tall" or 'Box 549 rejected: 25" height exceeds Max height of 24"'.

What's the best idiom to get this information into the log?  Do I have to create a `FilterResult` object that is returned from the `PassesFilter` method? Or I guess I could also throw an exception and catch it and log it? Or something else?

I happen to be using C++.

**Update**

In addition to logging I might want to also present a message to the user in the UI.

Answer (score 2):

I can see two main options here; an enum could be returned, or you could use an exception.

Personally, I would use an exception, but I'm not an experience C++ programmer, so I'm not sure if it fits the common idiom of the language.

Answer (score 1):

Ultimately, logging is instrumentation; something a bit more humane than debugging symbols or profiling instrumentation;  the logging should not have an effect on program flow, it should only faithfully report on it.

> Do I have to create a FilterResult object that is returned from the PassesFilter method?

If you want to have logging at that level, then it should be the `PassesFilter` method that actually logs a message.  To associate the filter result with a particular box, just emit a log message with the box identifier just before (or after) the filter method is called.   It is then up to the logging system to associate the two messages and do something fancy with them, or not.

> Or I guess I could also throw an exception and catch it and log it?

I wouldn't do this;  At least, not for the purposes of logging.  Exceptions are great, if they represent meaningful program flow.  It's also OK to instrument exceptions in a log file, but the step of creating an exception for the purposes of instrumentation is not going to make your code any better.

```
bool BoxFilterClass::PassesFilter(const Box & box){
    if (box.height > BoxFilterClass::MAX_HEIGHT) {
        Log.Debug(format("Box %s to tall, expected %s, actual: %s", box.id, BoxFilterClass::MAX_HEIGHT, box.height));
        return false;
    }
    else if (box.weight > BoxFilterClass::MAX_WEIGHT) {
        Log.Debug(format("Box %s to heavy, expected %s , actual: %s", box.id, BoxFilterClass::MAX_WEIGHT, box.weight));
        return false;
    }
    // and so on
    return true;
}
```

Comment: I guess I have resistance to logging in the Filter class as I'm trying to keep the logging as a concern of the consuming class while keeping the Filter class "pure".  And it's possible this goal is not justified but that's what's in my head. As another example, how about if instead of logging I wanted to present a message to the user, would you still suggest the same type of solution?

Comment: Logging is two separate concerns, "What is happening" and "Who cares?",  The "Who Cares" bit is hard to predict, and you should take pains not to make assumptions about it.  To be useful, though, logging should address the "What's happening" part to the highest detail, and as close to where the action is as is possible.

Answer (score 0):

For these situations, You can come up with a Response class which has a list of warnings, errors and information messages.

In this way, You can keep on adding errors to this response and return it back to the caller.

Also you dont have to add code in all the methods for logging errors. In a higher level(facade caller), you can add a check that if the response has errors or warnings, You can log them all.

Something like this (pseudo)

public class Response {

```
List<String> errors;
List<String> warnings;
List<String> infos;

}
```

In your code

```
foreach(Box box in boxes)
{
    if(boxFilter.PassesFilter(box))
    {
      // do something useful
    }
    else
    {
      response.addError(format("Box %s was rejected", box.BoxId))
      return response;
    }
}
```

--- In a higher level for all callers

```
If(response.hasErrors or warnings) {

logger.log(response.getErrors());
logger.log(response.getWarnings());


}
```

Comment: If I understand you correctly I think you're solving a slightly different problem than the one I have.  It looks like you're talking about aggregating errors in a for loop.  Instead, my question is about the fact that only the PassesFilter method has details about what happened and how does it communicate that back to the caller so the caller can log it.